# Serializing NSManagedObject

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm using a category on NSManagedObject, called NSManagedObject+Serialization.h located here https://gist.github.com/nuthatch/5607405.

Everything pretty much works great, but I need to implement this but not sure how? I want to skip some objects.

```
- (NSDictionary*) toDictionary {
// Check to see there are any objects that should be skipped in the traversal.
// This method can be optionally implemented by NSManagedObject subclasses.
NSMutableSet *traversedObjects = nil;
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(serializationObjectsToSkip)]) {
    traversedObjects = [self performSelector:@selector(serializationObjectsToSkip)];
}
return [self toDictionaryWithTraversalHistory:traversedObjects];
```

}

How do I add object relationships to be skipped?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your managed object subclass you must implement the `serializationObjectsToSkip`:

```
- (NSMutableSet*) serializationObjectsToSkip
{
    NSMutableSet* objectsToSkip = [NSMutableSet new];

    //Here you select objects that relate to this object and you don't want to serialise.
    //Insert them into `objectsToSkip`

    return objectsToSkip;
}
```

However, the implementation of the serialisation looks buggy (lines 80 and 93) ... (if you don't supply all objects to skip in advance)

The `toDictionary` of the `relatedObject` is skipped and so objects that the related objects may want to skip will not be added to the traversal history set ...

A quick fix might be to replace these lines with the full implementation of `toDictionary` and merging the traversal history set and the `objectsToSkip` sets returned ...

A better solution will be to change the signature of the `toDictionary` method to accept the traversal history and do the set merging there and replace the above lines with `toDictionary` of the related object.